# Expression or statement incorrect or possibly unbalanced (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, if-statement

```
if ((x % 2) == 1)
x = x - 1;
end
```

I don't get what I did wrong and can't find anything online, it's suppose to make a number even by subtracting 1 if it's odd btw.

Answer (score 0):

% is the comment character in matlab.
Replace (x % 2) with mod(x,2) in your expression

Answer (score 0):

`%` is not used for taking a modulus in MATLAB. In MATLAB, all the text that comes in a line after `%` is non-executable. Read the documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/symbol-reference.html#bsgigzp-40).

For your problem, replace `(x % 2)` with any of following:

1. `mod(x,2)`
2. `rem(x,2)`